# twoSum Algorithm : How to improve this?

Tags: java

I felt like doing an algorithm and found this problem on [leetcode](http://www.leetcode.com)

> Given an array of integers, find two numbers such that they add up to a specific target number.
>
> The function twoSum should return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to the target, where index1 must be less than index2. Please note that your returned answers (both index1 and index2) are not zero-based.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.
>
> Input: numbers={2, 7, 11, 15}, target=9
>
> Output: index1=1, index2=2

My solution is O(n^2). I wanted to know if there is better way of doing this? like O(n) or O(nlogn)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ReturnIndex {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
        int tail = numbers.length-1;
        int[] n = new int[2];
        for (int i=0;i<tail;i++) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<tail;j++) {
                if(target ==(numbers[i]+numbers[j])) {
                    n[0] = i+1;
                    n[1] = j+1;
                }
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] s = {150,24,79,50,88,345,3};
        int value = 200;
        ReturnIndex r = new ReturnIndex();
        int[] a = r.twoSum(s,value);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: this problem has good solutions with _dynamic programming_

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**`O(n log n)` time, `O(1)` memory (not counting the list):**

1. First, sort the list. This should take `O(n log n)` time, as most sort functions do.
2. Iterate through the list, which should take `O(n)` time in the outer loop. At this point you can do a binary search for the closest matching integer in a sorted sublist, which should take `O(log n)` time. This stage should wind up taking `O(n log n)` total.

*Edit:* Check out Max's answer below. It's still O(n log n) time and O(1) memory, but he avoids the binary searches by walking a pointer from each end of the list.

**`O(n)` time, `O(n)` memory:**

Build a hash table, which should have `O(1)` insertion and `O(1)` contains. Then, in a `O(n)` outer loop, for each number `i`, check if `total - i` is in the hash table. If not, add it; if so, then you've got your two numbers.

Either way, you would need an additional scan through the array to get the indices, but that's no problem--it only takes `O(n)` time. If you wanted to avoid it you could keep the original index in the sorted list or hash table as needed, but that has a memory footprint instead of a time footprint.

Comment: Please re-read the question, its not about returning the elements which add up to target

Comment: Beat me to it : ( .. also note that in the first solution, you can cut down on the size of the list after sorting by eliminating all numbers greater than the target sum.

Comment: @SuperMan - Once you have the elements it is trivial to get the indices from the original list.

Comment: @JamesSwift, it is trivial, but either requires memory (to keep the mappings between sorted and unsorted arrays), or time (to iterate over the unsorted array).

Answer (score 19):

Sort the array. Make two pointers point at first and last (x and X). Run this in a loop:

```
if      (a[X]+a[x] >  N) then X-- 
else if (a[X]+a[x] <  N) then x++
else if (a[X]+a[x] == N) then found.

if (x > X) then no numbers exist.
```

`O(nlogn)` time, `O(1)` memory

Comment: You are supposed to return location of the elements, not check if the target is available in the array

Comment: I had to play with this solution for 10 minutes to prove to myself that it's correct, but it is as far as I can tell. It's also elegant, and completes in `O(n log n)` time for the sort and `O(1)` memory beyond the list.

Comment: It bugged me too first. Think of it that way: Call your solution (a and A). When you start, a[X]>=A and a[x]<=a. @Jeff. This bugged me too at first. I think of it that way: At some point, you reach the point where a[X]=A or a[x]=a. Say it is a[X]=A first (or at the same time). By then, you have a[x]<=a, so a[x]+a[X]<=target. Your only choice is to increment x. I.e. you will never pass the correct X. Same goes with x.  Max => nice solution!

Comment: Can someone explain how this is O(nlogn) ?

Comment: What if I want to return the index from the original array before sorting, ex. `array: [3,2,4]
target: 6`, by using your solution it returns `[0,2] ` but answer is `[1,2]`

Answer (score 2):

Below you can find a solution in which the two numbers could be found in **`O(n log n)`** time:

```
1- Sort the numbers in ascending (or descending) order             // O(n log n)

2- Compute diff = target - item for each item                      // O(n) 

3- For each calculated diff, look up the calculated value in the sorted items 
   using the Binary search algorithm                               // O(n log n)
```

A complete, working implementation in Java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NumbersFinder {

    class Item{
        private int value;
        private int index;

        public Item(int value, int index){
            this.value = value;
            this.index = index;
        }

        public int getValue(){
            return value;
        }

        public int getIndex(){
            return index;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> find(int[] values, int target){      
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            items.add(new Item(values[i], i));

        items = quicksort(items);
        ArrayList<Integer> diffs = computeDiffs(items, target);

        Item item1 = null;
        Item item2 = null;

        boolean found = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < diffs.get(i) && !found; i++){
            item1 = items.get(i);
            item2 = searchSortedItems(items, diffs.get(i), 0, items.size());
            found = item2 != null;
        }
        if(found){
            ArrayList<Item> result = new ArrayList<Item>();
            result.add(item1);
            result.add(item2);
            return result;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    // find "value" in the sorted array of "items" using Binary search in O(log n)
    private Item searchSortedItems(ArrayList<Item> items, Integer value, int lower, int upper) {
        if(lower > upper)
            return null;
        int middle = (lower + upper)/2;
        Item middleItem = items.get(middle);
        if(middleItem.getValue() == value)
            return middleItem;
        else if(middleItem.getValue() < value)
            return searchSortedItems(items, value, middle+1, upper);
        else
            return searchSortedItems(items, value, lower, middle-1);
    }

    // Simply calculates difference between the target value and each item in the array; O(n)
    private ArrayList<Integer> computeDiffs(ArrayList<Item> items, int target) {
        ArrayList<Integer> diffs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)
            diffs.add(target - items.get(i).getValue());
        return diffs;
    }

    // Sorts items using QuickSort algorithm in O(n Log n)
    private ArrayList<Item> quicksort(ArrayList<Item> items) {
        if (items.size() <= 1)
            return items;
        int pivot = items.size() / 2;
        ArrayList<Item> lesser = new ArrayList<Item>();
        ArrayList<Item> greater = new ArrayList<Item>();
        int sameAsPivot = 0;
        for (Item item : items) {
            if (item.getValue() > items.get(pivot).getValue())
                greater.add(item);
            else if (item.getValue() < items.get(pivot).getValue())
                lesser.add(item);
            else
                sameAsPivot++;
        }
        lesser = quicksort(lesser);
        for (int i = 0; i < sameAsPivot; i++)
            lesser.add(items.get(pivot));
        greater = quicksort(greater);
        ArrayList<Item> sorted = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (Item item : lesser)
            sorted.add(item);
        for (Item item: greater)
            sorted.add(item);
        return sorted;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] s = {150,24,79,50,88,345,3};
        int value = 200;

        NumbersFinder finder = new NumbersFinder();
        ArrayList<Item> numbers = finder.find(s, value);

        if(numbers != null){
            System.out.println("First Number Found = " + numbers.get(0).getValue() + " ; Index = " + + numbers.get(0).getIndex());
            System.out.println("Second Number Found = " + numbers.get(1).getValue() + " ; Index = " + + numbers.get(1).getIndex());
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("No such two numbers found in the array!");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
First Number Found = 50 ; Index = 3
Second Number Found = 150 ; Index = 0
```

Comment: It would be very nice to post the link where you got the idea (or a link pointing to the book that helped you).

Comment: No, I didn't copy from anywhere! find it! I am by the way writing the Java code and will post the code soon. :-)

Comment: If it works, then it's good to see there are really good developers around here.

Answer (score 1):

One line solution in python :

```
class Solution(object):
    """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
    """
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):            
        x = [[i, nums.index(target-j)] for i,j in enumerate(nums) if nums.count(target-j) > 0 and nums.index(target-j)!=i]

        return x.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can provide an O(n) time solution, but his memory cannot be O(1)

First you declare a key-value pair , where key is the value in the array of integers and value is the index in the array of integers. And, you need to declare a hash table to hold the key-value pairs.
Then you need to iterate through the entire array of integers,
if the value of this array (=sum - array[i]) is in the hash table, congratulations you found it, 
if not, it is stored in the hash table.

So the entire time spent is the time to insert and query the hash table.
Memory is the size of the hash table.

My English is not very good, I hope I can help you.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] array = {150,24,79,50,88,345,3};
    int sum = 200;


    Map<Integer,Integer> table = new HashMap<>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        int key = sum - array[i];
        if(table.containsKey(key)){
            builder.append("index1=").append(table.get(key)).
                    append(" index2=").append(i);
        }else{
            table.put(array[i],i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(builder);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Prayer mentioned above, here is the accepted answer.

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] resultarray=new int[2];
        for (int i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++){
            for(int k=i+1;k<nums.length;k++)
            {
                 if(target==nums[i]+nums[k])
                 {
                     resultarray[0]=i;
                     resultarray[1]=k;
                 }
            }
        }
        return resultarray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The naïve solution to the two-sum problem is `O(n^2)`, s.t. `n` is the length of the array of numbers provided.

However, we can do better by using a hash-map of the values seen so far (key=number, value=index) and checking if the complement is already there (`O(1)`) as we iterate over the numbers. This approach is optimal for an **unsorted array**:

- Runtime complexity: `O(n)`
- Space complexity: `O(n)` -- though if there is a solution, in practice this would be `O(n/2)`

Given the OP's question:

- does **not** specify whether the input array is sorted or not (it is, therefore, safe to assume the input array can be anything), and
- specifically asks for **indexes** of the provided array, as opposed to the actual numbers, any kind of solution sorting the array would need to copy it beforehand, keep a mapping of indexes between the sorted array and the unsorted one, or iterate over the original array, hence costing memory (`O(n)`) or time (`O(n)`), depending on the approach chosen. Therefore, the 1st part of the [(currently) accepted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13042928/1328979) is, strictly speaking, *incorrect*.

Optimal solution:

- In Python:

```python
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        seen = {}
        for j, num in enumerate(nums):
            i = seen.get(target-num, -1)
            if i != -1:
                return [i+1, j+1]
            seen[num] = j
        return [-1, -1]
```

- In Java:

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        final Map<Integer, Integer> seen = new HashMap<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; ++j) {
            final Integer i = seen.get(target - nums[j]); // One hash-map access v.s. two when using contains beforehand.
            if (i != null) {
                return new int[]{ i+1, j+1 };
            }
            numbers.put(nums[j], j);
        }
        return new int[]{-1, -1};
    }
}
```

Note that by construction, if the complement is present in the map/dictionary, then the index stored will always be lower than the current index. Hence the following proposition is verified:

> index1 must be less than index2

Also note that the OP's question needed 1-based indexes, which is what I've provided above, but the Leetcode question referred to seems to have been updated since then, and now is 0-based: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(n):

```
public int[] findSumMatched(int[] numbers, int target) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> mapOfNumbers = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        int secondNumber = target - numbers[i];
        if (mapOfNumbers.get(secondNumber) != null){
            return new int[] {mapOfNumbers.get(secondNumber), i};
        }
        mapOfNumbers.put(numbers[i], i);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        out_list=[] 
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(len(nums)):
                if(target-nums[i]) == nums[j] and i != j:
                    out_list.append(i)
        return out_list
```

Comment: Please add more context to the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it this way:

1. Order your array from smaller to lower value
2. Loop over your array the way you have it but exit the loop early whenever

   target <(numbers[i]+numbers[j])
3. Once you have the value of your two elements such that n[0] + n[1] = target, look back at the original array to find their index.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my cpp solution with O(nlog(n)):

```
vector<int> two_sum(vector<int> &numbers, int target) {
    vector<int> result;
    vector<int> numbers_dup = vector<int>(numbers);

    sort(numbers_dup.begin(), numbers_dup.end());

    int left = 0, right = numbers_dup.size() - 1;
    while(left <= right) {
        int sum = numbers_dup[left] + numbers_dup[right];

        if(sum == target) {
            //find the idex of numbers_dup[left] and numbers_dup[right]
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
                if(numbers[i] == numbers_dup[left] || numbers[i] == numbers_dup[right]) {
                    result.push_back(i);
                }
                if(result.size() == 2) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(sum > target) {
            right--;
        }
        else {
            left++;
        }
    }
}
```

Check out my blog for the detailed explanation.
https://algorithm.pingzhang.io/Array/two_sum_problem.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer using HashMap in java with two passes of the array. Assuming that there are no duplicate elements in the array and there is exactly one solution exists.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TwoSum {

    int[] index = new int[2];
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        int length = nums.length;
        //initialize return values assuming that pair for the given target
        //doesn't exist
        index[0]=-1;
        index[1]=-1;
        //sanity check
        if(length<1) return index;

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> numHash = new HashMap<>(length);
        //get the values from array into HashMap assuming that there aren't duplicate values
        for(int i=0; i<length;i++)
        {
            numHash.put(nums[i],i);
        }

        //check for the value in the array and the difference between target and it. Assume that only
        //one such pair exists
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            int val1 = nums[i];
            int val2=target-val1;
            //make sure that it doesn't return the index of the first number in the pait you are searching for
            if( numHash.containsKey(val2) && numHash.get(val2)!=i){
                index[0]=i;
                index[1] =numHash.get(target-nums[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int []resultarray=new int[2];
        for (int i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++){
            for(int k=1;k<nums.length;k++)
            {
                 if(target==nums[i]+nums[k])
                 {
                     resultarray[0]=nums[i];
                     resultarray[1]=nums[k];
                 }
            }
        }
 return resultarray;
    }
```

Comment: Some explanations would significantly improve the quality of your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is my python solution

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """

        copy_dict = {}
        for pos in range(0, len(nums)):
            if nums[pos] not in copy_dict.keys():
                copy_dict[nums[pos]] = [pos]
            else:
                copy_dict[nums[pos]].append(pos)

        def get_sum_indexes(sorted_array, target):
            right_pointer = len(sorted_array) - 1
            left_pointer = 0
            while left_pointer < len(sorted_array) or right_pointer > 0:
                if sorted_array[right_pointer] + sorted_array[left_pointer] == target:
                    return [sorted_array[left_pointer], sorted_array[right_pointer]]
                elif sorted_array[right_pointer] + sorted_array[left_pointer] > target:
                    right_pointer -= 1
                elif sorted_array[right_pointer] + sorted_array[left_pointer] < target:
                    left_pointer += 1
            return None
        sum_numbers = get_sum_indexes(sorted(nums), target)
        if len(copy_dict[sum_numbers[0]]) == 1:
            answer_1 = copy_dict[sum_numbers[0]][0]
        else:
            answer_1 = copy_dict[sum_numbers[0]][0]

        if len(copy_dict[sum_numbers[1]]) == 1:
            answer_2 = copy_dict[sum_numbers[1]][0]
        else:
            answer_2 = copy_dict[sum_numbers[1]][1]
        return sorted([answer_1, answer_2])

print(Solution().twoSum(nums=[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5], target=-8))
print(Solution().twoSum(nums=[-3, -3], target=-6))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the list in non-decreasing order. It takes `O(nlogn)` time complexity.
2. Find the two numbers, which can be done in `O(n)` time.
3. Find the two indices of the two numbers, which can be done in `O(n)` time.

Overall complexity is `O(nlogn)`.

Implementation in python:

```
class Solution:
  def twoSum(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    p = nums[:]
    p.sort() #sorting in -> O(nlogn)
    r = len(nums)-1
    l =0 

    #find the indices -> O(n)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
      if(p[l] + p[r]<target): 
        l += 1
      elif (p[l] + p[r]>target): 
        r -=1
      else :
        first_num = p[l]
        second_num = p[r]

    #find the indices of the numbers -> O(n)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
      if(nums[i]==first_num):
        first_index = i
      elif (nums[i]==second_num):
        second_index = i
    return [first_index,second_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift code with Time Complexity O(n) and Space complexity O(n):

```
import UIKit

class Solution{
    func twoSum(_ nums: [Int], _ target: Int) -> [Int]{
        var finalArray = [Int]()
        var newDictionary = [Int:Int]()
        for i in 0..<nums.count{
            let complement = target - nums[i]
            if newDictionary[complement] != nil && newDictionary[complement] != i{

                finalArray.append(newDictionary[complement]!)
                finalArray.append(i)
                return finalArray
            }
            newDictionary[nums[i]] = i

        }
        return []
    }
}

func main(){

    let solution = Solution()
    print("All Good" ,solution.twoSum([1, 3, 4 , 5], 6))
}

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

An O(n) solution in c++ using hash map only exploiting **Commutative rule** of Addition in real numbers.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        unordered_map<int, int> my_map;
          for ( int i = 0 ; i < nums.size(); i++ ){
                if(my_map.find(target - nums[i]) != my_map.end()){
                    return vector<int> {my_map[target - nums[i]], i};
                }  
                my_map[nums[i]] = i ;
          }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the answers and they don't seem to handle the edge cases properly. Hence, throwing my two cents for python3 solution that handles the edge cases. I used Max's algorithm to implement it:

```
   def twoSum(nums, target):
    output=[]
    arr=sorted(nums)
    x=0
    y=-1
    X=len(nums)-1
    while x<X:
        if (arr[X]+arr[x] >  target):
            X-=1 
        elif (arr[X]+arr[x] <  target):
            x+=1
        elif (arr[X]+arr[x] == target):
            #print("Found",arr[X],arr[x])
            num1=arr[x]
            num2=arr[X]
            x+=1
            X-=1 
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if num1 == nums[i] and y==-1:
            index1=i
            y=i
        elif num2 == nums[i]:
            index2=i         
    return [index1, index2]
```

N.B. It's important to consider edge cases and inputs like the following

```
print(twoSum([3,2,4],  6)) # [1,2]
print(twoSum([3,3],  6))  # [0,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Efficient Solution.

**Time Complexity - O(n)** and **Space Complexity - O(1)**

Sol: Will take two-pointer(start_pointer and end_pointer). Initially start_pointer point at the first index and end_pointer point to the last.

Add both the element (**sum = array[start_pointer] + array[last_pointer]**. After that check, if the **sum > target** element or not. If yes decrease the **end_pointer** else increase **start_pointer**.  If **sum = target**, means you got the indexes.

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {

    int[] arr = new int[2]; // to store result
    int sum=0;

    int start_pointer=0;     
    int end_pointer = (numbers.length)-1;

    while(start_pointer<=end_pointer){

        sum=numbers[start_pointer]+numbers[end_pointer]; 

        if(sum>target)
            end_pointer-=1;
        else if(sum<target)
            start_pointer+=1;
        else{
            arr[0]=start_pointer;
            arr[1]=end_pointer;
            break;
        }       
    }       
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: It works only If array is sorted while **in case of unsorted array list you will get wrong result.**

Answer (score 0):

We can do with HashMap and the time complexity would be O(n)

```
public class ReturnIndicesOfElementsAddToSum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] nums = {2, 7, 11, 15};
    int target = 18;

    if(!getIndices(nums,target)) {
        System.out.println("No such numbers found");
    }

}

static boolean getIndices(int[] nums, int target) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<>();
    boolean numFound = false;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++) {
        int temp = target - nums[i];
        indexMap.put(nums[i], i);
        if(indexMap.containsKey(temp)) {
            System.out.printf("%d and %d adds upto the target value and indices are %d and %d"
                            , nums[i], temp, i, indexMap.get(temp));
            numFound = true;
        }
    }
    return numFound;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using HashMap this is also a solution if **complexity for search in HashMap** will in order of O(logn) then in worst case the complexity will be **O(nlogn)**

```
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        
        int [] resultIndex = null;
        
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            int temp = target - nums[i];
            
            if(map.containsKey(temp)){
                resultIndex = new int[2];
                resultIndex[0]=map.get(temp);
                resultIndex[1]=i;
            }else{
                map.put(nums[i],i);
            }
        }
        return resultIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, but what's wrong with this O(n) solution?

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++){
        if (nums[i] + nums[i+1] == target)
            return new int[] {i, i+1};
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It just checks if numbers next to each other match the target. Think about giving the following parameters: nums: {12, 3, 23, 4} and target: 7. The return should be [1, 3] but your answer does not find it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem would be,

```
public int[] twoSums(int[] unsortedNum, int target) {
        int[] nums = Arrays.copyOf(unsortedNum, unsortedNum.length);
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        boolean isResultFound = false;
        int start = 0;
        int end = nums.length-1;
        while(!(start > end)) {
            if(nums[start]+nums[end] > target){
                end--;
            } else if (nums[start]+nums[end] < target){
                start++;
            } else if(nums[start] + nums[end] == target){
                isResultFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isResultFound){
            int s = -1;
            int e = -1;
            for(int i = 0; i< unsortedNum.length; i++){
                if(s != -1 && e != -1){
                    break;
                }
                if(s == -1 && unsortedNum[i] == nums[start]){
                    s = i;
                } else if(e == -1 && unsortedNum[i] == nums[end]) {
                    e = i;
                }
            }
            return new int[] {s,e};
        }
        // for element not found
        return new int[]{-1,-1};
    }
```

In the end, if you get -1, -1 as the index then you can say that elements not found which could sum to the target element.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int[] sortedNums = Arrays.copyOf(nums, nums.length);
    Arrays.sort(sortedNums);
            
    int leftSortedIndex = 0;
    int rightSortedIndex = sortedNums.length - 1;
    
    while(leftSortedIndex < rightSortedIndex) {
        int sum = sortedNums[leftSortedIndex] + sortedNums[rightSortedIndex];
        if(sum == target) {
            break;
        } else if(sum < target) {
            leftSortedIndex++;
        } else {
            rightSortedIndex--;
        }
    }
            
    int leftIndex = -1;
    int rightIndex = -1;
    for(int index=0; index < nums.length; index++) {
        if(leftIndex == -1 && nums[index] == sortedNums[leftSortedIndex]) {
            leftIndex = index;
            continue;
        }
        
        if(rightIndex == -1 && nums[index] == sortedNums[rightSortedIndex]) {
            rightIndex = index;
        } 
    }
    
    
    return (new int[] {leftIndex, rightIndex});
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    int[] sortedNums = Arrays.copyOf(nums, nums.length);
    Arrays.sort(sortedNums);
            
    int leftSortedIndex = 0;
    int rightSortedIndex = sortedNums.length - 1;
    
    while(leftSortedIndex < rightSortedIndex) {
        int sum = sortedNums[leftSortedIndex] + sortedNums[rightSortedIndex];
        if(sum == target) {
            break;
        } else if(sum < target) {
            leftSortedIndex++;
        } else {
            rightSortedIndex--;
        }
    }
            
    int leftIndex = -1;
    int rightIndex = -1;
    for(int index=0; index < nums.length; index++) {
        if(leftIndex == -1 && nums[index] == sortedNums[leftSortedIndex]) {
            leftIndex = index;
        } else if(rightIndex == -1 && nums[index] == sortedNums[rightSortedIndex]) {
            rightIndex = index;
        }
    }
    
    
    return (new int[] {leftIndex, rightIndex});
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

If anyone want for C this might help...It is brute forced not with hashtable!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i,j,l,target,m,n;
    printf("Enter how many elements you want :\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    int array[i];

    printf("Input elements\n" );
    for (j=0;j<i;j++)
    scanf("%d",&array[j]);
    
    printf("[");
    for (l=0;l<i;l++)
    printf(" %d ",array[l] );
    printf("]\n");

    printf("Input the target :");
    scanf("%d",&target);

    for (m=0;m<i;m++)
    {
        for (n=m+1;n<i;n++)
        {
            if ((array[m]+array[n])==target)
            {
                printf("Their indices is \n[%d,%d]",m,n);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.