# Get sum of elements in a list python

Tags: python

Given :

```
[1, 3, 46, 1, 3, 9]
```

Find distinct combination between these to get target number = 47, as many  as possible. 46 + 1 and 1 + 46 are consider same.

My code :

```
def stockPairs(stocksProfit, target):
    # Write your code here
    print(stocksProfit)
    #print(target)

    count = 0
    for t, sp in enumerate(stocksProfit):
        #print(stocksProfit[t])
        for l in range(1, len(stocksProfit)): 
            total = stocksProfit[t] + stocksProfit[l]
            #print(total, stocksProfit[t], stocksProfit[l] )
            if total == target :

                count = count + 1
    return count
```

expected outcome is 1, since I only want distinct combination

Comment: What are you stuck with so far?

Comment: I don't know how to start the summing between the elements. between two elements

Comment: @dee, your question is getting downvoted to oblivion because it's obvious that you haven't actually searched for the answer. there is a builtin function `sum()` that will do this for you, but you need to actually look for it. you probably exerted more effort in writing this question than you would have if you just typed the title of the question into Google and clicked [the first link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-find-sum-of-elements-in-list/)

Comment: wrong library function, combinations. Either way, you can't just say "do this code for me" Definitely don't look up two sum.

Comment: @KennyOstrom update my codes

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations for brute force, variations of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042798/twosum-algorithm-how-to-improve-this to speed it up using a set, but it will take more work to include more than two different items. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 : Combination of any 2 numbers

```
import itertools

input_list=[1, 3, 46, 1, 3, 9]
combinations_of_2 = itertools.combinations(input_list,2)

sum_of_47 = [ sorted(combination) for combination in combinations_of_2 if sum(combination) == 47 ]
print(sum_of_47)
```

Output

```
[[1, 46], [1, 46]]
```

Solution 2 : Combination of any number of elements from the list

```
import itertools
input_list=[1, 3,44,2, 1, 3, 9]

all_combinations = [ itertools.combinations(input_list, r) for r in range(len(input_list)+1) ]

sum_of_47 = [ sorted(combination) for combination_by_len in all_combinations for combination in combination_by_len if sum(combination) == 47 ]

print(sum_of_47)
```

Output

```
[[3, 44], [3, 44], [1, 2, 44], [1, 2, 44]]
```

*Note: Both solutions will have duplicates.Need to pass through a logic to remove duplicate tuples*